# mongoose and typescript - can't create field called alias

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I'm porting my project over to typescript and I'm having trouble with my schema with a field called alias. I'm getting this error:

```
Types of property 'alias' are incompatible.
Type 'StringConstructor' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

I know this is because mongoose has alias fields (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#aliases). My question is, how do I escape this?

My code for reference:

```
import mongoose, { Schema, Model } from 'mongoose';

const userSchema = new Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  alias: String
});
```

Thanks.

EDIT: this also doesn't work:

```
import mongoose, { Schema, Model } from 'mongoose';

const userSchema = new Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  alias: {type: String, required: true}
});
```

with this error:

```
Types of property 'alias' are incompatible.
Type '{ type: string; required: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#typeKey

Answer (score 0):

`Type 'StringConstructor' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)`

**Error clearly defines that :**

You are assigning the `Data Type` of the field to alias, but `alias` should be named, not a type, that can be used to show that field with the alias name.

Change this :

`alias: String`

to

`alias: "String"` // <-- this should be name like "user_id" or something like this

Comment: I think there is still a conflict with the alias type that is already existing in mongoose. For example, if I want to do: ``alias: {type: String, required: true}`` or ``alias: {type: "String", required: true}``, i still get an error. Thanks

Comment: Yes alias is reserved keyword for mongoose for aliasing the field name

Comment: I don't think so, you should use diff name instead of that

Comment: There must be a way. everything works fine if i do ``const mongoose = require('mongoose')``. However, when i do ``import mongoose from 'mongoose'`` it does not work. It must be something with @types/mongoose, and there must be a way to escape this